# Visual Studio Code - Jump from interface definition to implementation

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code for PHP development. I can click on a method and select "Go to definition" which will point me to the interface which defines the method. What I'm missing is a operation to jump from the interface definition to the place where the method is implemented.

I can use "Find all references" on the interface definition, among all function calls this will also list the implementation but it is hard to find them if a method is used in many different places. Is there a way to search only for all implementations of a method?

Comment: AFAIK VS Code doesn't support this out of the box. Have you checked the [extension marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=php%20find%20implementation&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance)? Maybe you find an extension for this.

Comment: Thanks, right now I use the extensions bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client, bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client and neilbrayfield.php-docblocker. I also tried felixfbecker.php-intellisense. None of them provides this functionality. I'm happy for any pointer if someone knows a extension which does the trick.

Comment: Did you find a way to solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Not supported by VSCode or by any extension
for now, you can use regular expression, lets say you want to find all classes that implement an interface called `Interface` you then can use this regular expression in the search bar

```
implements(.*)( |,)Interface(,|$| )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ([Laravel Goto](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=absszero.vscode-laravel-goto)) extension, And go to defineition block using `ctrl + click`